# how to enumerate footer line in longtable?

Tags: tables, longtable

The simple solution provide wrong number for footer line :(

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,
              russian,
              twoside,
%              draft
%              slashbox
              ]{extarticle}
\usepackage[a4 paper, portrait,%
tmargin=20mm,%
bmargin=20mm,%
inner=15mm,%
outer=15mm,%
headheight=0mm,headsep=0mm,footskip=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}

\newcounter{LineCNT}
\newcommand{\MYline}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{LineCNT}\theLineCNT&#1&& \\ \hline
}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{r|c|c|c}
\hline
It&is&table's&head \\ \hline \hline \endhead
\MYline{} \endfoot
\MYline{Some data}
\MYline{enather data}
\MYline{more info}
\MYline{}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Why this happens is clear enough.

But it is unclear how to fix this.

Comment: Replace  `\MYline{}\endfoot}` with `\hline\endfoot`?

Comment: @Bernard not placing footline more easy but I need footline for some calculation...

Comment: I don't understand: with \hline, you'll have a footline, but no counter increased by 1 and  displayed. Or do I misunderstand the situation?

Comment: @Bernard becouse you thinking in wrong direction. you do not understand my task: the "Some data" line must be numered by 1 (in this example) and footer line must be numered by 5... and you solution eqvivalent simply skipping footline

Comment: try the following *mwe*: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}\newcounter{LineCNT}\newcommand{\MYline}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{LineCNT}\theLineCNT&#1&& \\ 
  \hline}\begin{document}\begin{longtable}{r|c|c|c}\hlineIt  &   is  &   table's &   head    \\     \hline \hline 
    \endhead
\MYline{last line on the page, but processed first}     \endfoot
\MYline{Some data}\MYline{more info}\MYline{}\end{longtable}\end{document}` and analyse result. hopefully it will make clear what you doing wrong.

Comment: @Zarko as I have writen in original post it is clear what happens and why the foot line get numer 1. it is unclear what to do to fix that.

Comment: with above test i try to show the cause of your problem. in my answer below i suggest a solution. maybe you will like it :-)

Comment: Do you have more pages where you need other numbers in the footer?  Do you *really* a footer? As it is saved in a box it is rather difficult to get variable content in it.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

i must confess that i don't understand what you like to achieve. just automatic numbering of rows in table? than the following *mwe* may work for you:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{array, longtable}
\newcounter{LineCNT}
\newcommand{\getCNT}{\refstepcounter{LineCNT}\theLineCNT}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{>{\getCNT}r|c|c|c}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{r}{It}
    &   is          &   table's &   head    \\
    \hline \hline
    \endhead
    \hline
\multicolumn{4}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{continue on the next page}}
    \endfoot
    \hline
    \endlastfoot
% table body
    &   Some data   &           &           \\
    &   more info   &           &           \\
    &   more info   &           &           \\
    &   more info   &           &           \\
    &   more info   &           &           \\
    &   more info   &           &           \\
    &   more info   &           &           \\
    &   more info   &           &           \\
    &   more info   &           &           \\
    &   more info   &           &           \\
    &   more info   &           &           \\
    &   more info   &           &           \\
    &   more info   &           &           \\
    &   more info   &           &           \\
    &   more info   &           &           \\
    &   more info   &           &           \\
    &   more info   &           &           \\
    &   more info   &           &           \\
    &   more info   &           &           \\
    &   more info   &           &           \\
    &   more info   &           &           \\
    &   more info   &           &           \\
    &   more info   &           &           \\
    &   more info   &           &           \\
    &   more info   &           &           \\
    &   more info   &           &           \\
    &   more info   &           &           \\
    &   more info   &           &           \\
    &   more info   &           &           \\
    &   more info   &           &           \\
    &   more info   &           &           \\
    &   more info   &           &           \\
    &   more info   &           &           \\
    &   more info   &           &           \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```